# Excel connector modifies the "date modified" property of the file - SSIS

Tags: excel, connection, ssis-2012

I am working with some excel files. The idea is to take only those that have been modified. But here I got the problem. When I am executing the all package, the Excel connector is modifying the the "date modified" with the system hour. These files have not the property "Read Only", and I can not do nothing regarding this because I just read the files from a specific folder.

What would be the best approach to face this issue?.

Comment: You can open a workbook as read-only with this: `Workbooks.Open Filename:=file_name, ReadOnly:=True`

Comment: Hi Elbert.Could you please explain a little bit more?. Or can you refer any link with an example. Thanks

Comment: Well, I'm talking about just VBA, not considering SSIS, and now I'm not sure if I'm right... but, from VBA inside EXCEL, you can open a workbook as a Read-Only, just with that line of code, where `file_name` is the name of the file that you want to open as read-only. [Workbooks.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx), here you can find some help.

Comment: If you specify DelayValidation on the Excel Connection Manager and then have your script task run first, is the date modified preserved? Might also need to specify it on any Data Flow Tasks that reference it as well

Answer (score 0):

This way you can Read the modified date of a file without open it, all from excel.

```
Sub test()
    Dim FD As FileDialog
    Dim i

    Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With FD
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each i In .SelectedItems
                MsgBox FileLastModified(i)
            Next i
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Function FileLastModified(ByVal strFullFileName As String)
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim f As Object
    Dim s As String

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFile(strFullFileName)

    s = UCase(strFullFileName) & vbCrLf
    s = s & "Last Modified: " & f.DateLastModified
    FileLastModified = s

    Set fs = Nothing: Set f = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Elbert. I have not problem by reading the "date modified" of the file. The problem here is that when I execute the package, the Excel connector inmmediatly is going to change that value. And this is what I need to stop happening. Because I am gonna be always reading a wrong date.